# MVC5 SimpleMembership WEBMATRIX

Tags: c#

I'm trying to implement SimpleMembership on my MVC5 project, and I'm using this tutorial: http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-simplemembership-in-asp.net-mvc-4.htm

When I launch my site, I get this error:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M7rUQ.png)

This is my webconfig file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301880
  -->
<configuration>

  <configSections>
    <!-- For more information on Entity Framework configuration, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=237468 -->
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="UporabnikContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDb;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=Uporabniki;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
<add name="IgraContext" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDb;Integrated Security=True;Initial Catalog=Igre;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
  <add name="Accounts" connectionString="Data Source=BALLOUTQT\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=Accounts;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="webpages:Version" value="3.0.0.0"/>
    <add key="webpages:Enabled" value="false"/>
    <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
    <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.3"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.3"/>



    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login"></forms>
    </authentication>

    <membership defaultProvider="SampleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SampleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </membership>

    <roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="SampleProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SampleProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleRoleProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"/>
      </providers>
    </roleManager>





  </system.web>
  <runtime>

    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages.Razor" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
            <dependentAssembly>
                <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Razor" publicKeyToken="31BF3856AD364E35" culture="neutral"/>
                <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
            </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Helpers" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.WebPages" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-3.0.0.0" newVersion="3.0.0.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="System.Web.Mvc" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35"/>
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-5.2.3.0" newVersion="5.2.3.0"/>
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <entityFramework>
    <contexts>
    <context type="dsr_vaja1.DAL.UporabnikContext, dsr_vaja1">
      <databaseInitializer type="dsr_vaja1.DAL.UporabnikINIT, dsr_vaja1"/>
    </context>
     <context type="dsr_vaja1.DAL.IgraContext, dsr_vaja1">
      <databaseInitializer type="dsr_vaja1.DAL.IgraINIT, dsr_vaja1"/>
    </context>
  </contexts>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
    <providers>
      <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer"/>
    </providers>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

I have a working SQLEXPRESS database, and two entityframework LOCALDB ones which I use for other things, my SQLEXPRESS one looks like this:
name: Accounts
table: 
col1: Id
col2: username
col3: password

this is my Account Controller

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    // GET: Account
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Login()
    {
        if (!WebSecurity.Initialized)
        {
            WebSecurity.InitializeDatabaseConnection("Accounts", "Users", "Id", "username", autoCreateTables:true);
        }

        return View();
    }
```

I have included all of the libraries, and I have the other logout/register stuff too but it's not important now.

Things I have tried:
-setting AutoCreateTables in the controller to false,
-deleting the empty machine.config files in the windows microsoft.net folder
-installing the Nugets:
   -Microsoft.Asp.WebPages.Data
   -Microsoft.Asp.WebPages.Webhelper
  BUT I couldn't install them, because I get the error:

"Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Unable to resolve dependencies. 'jQuery 1.10.2' is not compatible with 'bootstrap 3.3.7 constraint: jQuery (>= 1.9.1 && < 4.0.0)', 'jQuery.UI.Combined 1.12.1 constraint: jQuery (>= 1.12.4)', 'jQuery.Validation 1.11.1 constraint: jQuery (>= 1.4.4)', 'Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation 3.2.3 constraint: jQuery (>= 1.8.0)'.         0
"

The thing is I use bootstrap, and this is what I have on my master page:

```
 <link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/mojaskripta.js"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.js"></script>
```

My Jquery and Jquery UI work fine, so I don't know why it's saying that I have JQ 1.10.2

Comment: Edit: fixed the problem, had to update all the NUGETS in installed nugets.

Comment: I was about to say if you have there any packages config to show us because it is saying (>= 1.9.1 && < 4.0.0) from somewhere. Cheers